# ¿Como elimino una Fila de un DataGridView?

Tags: c#

Les Comento mi problemática, tengo un DataGridView donde ingreso items para realizar una venta, esto lo hago digitando el código en la primera columna y valiéndome del método CellValidating controlo que el producto exista en una base de datos, vale decir que en total tengo 7 columnas mas en donde en la mayoría hago restricciones como esta, ya sea controlar stock, validar descuentos a los productos, etc.

Mi problema es que si por casualidad o por descuido el usuario ingresa a la columna 'código item' debo saltarme esta validación, lo solucione creando un código que se la salte (un cero en mi caso). El problema es qu cuando intento eliminar esta fila me marca error, y debo eliminarla ya que interfiere con sumas que hago a la columna de precios por ejemplo.

¿Como podría solucionar esto sin que me genere errores? ¿Como podría programar que la fila se elimine cuando ingrese este código?

Acepto sugerencias y de antemano muchas Gracias.

Así es como valido la columna de 'código item'

```
if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() != "" && (e.FormattedValue.ToString().Length >= 6 && e.FormattedValue.ToString().Length <= 11))
{
      //Valido que no tenga items repetidos
      if (Obj_Vta.ItemRepetido(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), this.dtVentas))
      {
           this.dtVentas.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "No se Permiten Items Repetidos - Aumente Cantidad";
           e.Cancel = true;
      }
      else
      {//CONSULTO DE MANERA NORMA
          if (!this.Obj_Vta.BuscarItem(this.dtVentas, e,this.lblCod_TipCte.Text))
          {
              //SI EL ITEM NO EXISTE CANCELAMOS EL AVANCE
              e.Cancel = true;
          }
      }
}
else
{//EN CASO QUE LA CELDA ESTE VACIO O NO CUMPLA CON EL LARGO ADECUADO TENEMOS DOS POSIBILIDADES

    //SI EL VALOR ES 0: SE CANCELA LA OPERACION Y SE DEBERIA ELIMINAR ESA FILA
    if (e.FormattedValue.ToString() == "0")
    {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
    else
    {
    //EN CASO QUE LA NO QUIERA ELIMINAR LA FILA: MENSAJE DE INGRESE CODIGO CORRECTO O 0 SI QUIERE ABANDONAR
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.dtVentas.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "¡¡Ingrese un Codigo!! - 0 si quiere Abandonar";
    }
}
```

Y asi es como trato de eliminar la fila:

```
private void dtVentas_CellValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //METODO QUE SE EJECUTA CUANDO LA CELDA YA ESTA VALIDADA
    if (this.dtVentas.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "0")
    {
        this.dtVentas.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cual es el error que te esta dando cuando eliminas la fila

Comment: "Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException'"
"La operacion no se puede realizar en este controlador de eventos." creo que tiene que ver con que la fila aun no se ha validado. Es por eso que busco una alternativa de como solucionar esto.

Comment: dtVentas_CellValidated es un DataGridView?? no deberia de ser un boton

Comment: Si, lo se, es que necesito quitar esa fila cuando ingrese ese codigo automáticamente, sin botones o algo por el estilo

Comment: Y has probado con un `foreach`

Comment: ya lo hice dentro del CellValidated y el mismo resultado o en que evento me sugieres implementarlo?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76341/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-benjamin-garrido-h).

Comment: yo prefiero cargar mi informacion en un datatable y conectar my datagridview a un datasource apuntando a la datatable, es mejor practica asi ya que puedes manipular la informacion en la capa de datos (data table) y manipular el el gridview en la capa de presentacion y no tratarlo de hacer todo junto en un solo control

Comment: La programación que hice fue en base a requerimientos del cliente y el la quiere así. Aunque es una buena idea lo que planteas

Answer (score 2):

yo realize una practica similar con datagridview c#
bueno te conparto el codigo...

```
    // cabe mencionar que este codigo esta en un boton, evento click selecciono el grid a eliminar,
// tiene que seleccionar un elemento del grid.
        if (dgvCaptura.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
           // utilizo el foreach para iterar los registros.
           // con el metodo de RemoveAt. le mando el indice del elemento a eliminar
           foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dgvCaptura.SelectedRows)
           {
             dgvCaptura.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);                    
           }
        }
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Acabo de probar el código y si bien funciona dentro del contexto de un botón no lo puedo aplicar a lo que estoy buscando

Comment: intenta agregarlo dentro del contexto de dtVentas_CellValidated. tu condicion  dentro del foreach, cambiando el parametro de RemoveAt por item.Index,.. has pruebas}

Comment: Hice las pruebas y es el mismo resultado